# Monitoramento de processos

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de monitoramento de processos,  para pegar os programas em execução estou utilizando esta classe:  [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), mais não estou conseguindo encontrar um metodo para descontar o tempo ocioso, por exemplo só estou conseguindo mencionar o tempo total que o processo ficou aberto, gostaria de não considerar o tempo que este processo ficou minimizado ou parado.

Answer (score 1):

`Win32_Process` tem a propriedade `CreationDate`, que a apesar do nome é um DateTime. Para saber o tempo ocioso de um programa, basta descobrir o tempo total e subtrair o tempo do usuário (`UserModeTime`) e o tempo gasto núcleo (`KernelModeTime`)

Um exemplo, utilizando as classes padrão do C#

```
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var procs = Process.GetProcesses().Where( x => x.ProcessName.Contains( "chrome" ) ).ToList();
        foreach ( var proc in procs )
        {
            var timeTotal = DateTime.Now - proc.StartTime;
            var timeProc = proc.TotalProcessorTime;
            var timeIdle = timeTotal.Subtract( timeProc );

            Console.WriteLine( proc.Id + " total " + timeTotal + " user+kernel " + timeProc + " idle " + timeIdle );
        }
    }
```

Produz coisas como:

```
2570 total 1.18:52:22.8433460 user+kernel 00:48:02 idle 1.18:04:20.843346000:11:57.9100000
```